# Do i need transit visa for 2 hour layover Transit via (warsaw poland) to UK from Delhi?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, poland

I am an Indian citizen with a valid F1 visa of UK and I have a flight from Delhi to UK via warsaw poland a 2 hour layover on the same calendar day.

However, my airline is doesnot know whether transit visa and other sources is very mix absured information found .Could you please help me ?

do i need transit visa at poland as indian nationality passport holder

Comment: The UK doesn’t have an ‘F1’ visa type AFAIK

Comment: Neither does UK has an F1 visa nor does any official source has any absurd information. All three official sources, Polish official websites, EU official website and Timatic have clear info regarding the nationalities who need an airport transit visa for Poland, and India is not on the list (for airside transit).

Answer (score 2):

### If you have a single ticket/PNR :

TIMATIC states :

> > Visa required. TWOV (Transit Without Visa)
>
> Passengers transiting through Warsaw (WAW) and arriving from a
> non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight
> within 24 hours to a third country which is not a Schengen Member
> State. They must:
>
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

You won't need a visa

---

### If you are on multiple tickets :

It is extremely likely that you won't be allowed to board in India, even if you don't leave the transit area, if you don't have a Polish **C** (tourist) visa [Info about how to apply](https://www.gov.pl/web/india/c-type-schengen-visa)